# Jquery width not resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox

Surely, I'm doing something wrong but can't figure out what.
I have a **Lightbox** appearing with this package:  `featherlight.js`

**EDIT:** *Someone commented to make sure it's being called after. I can confirm it's being called after. I tested with a `console.log` returning the width and height of the Lightbox.*

Documentation says it take 250ms to appear.
I called it like so:

```
$.featherlight("#previewCompleteContainer", {afterOpen: function(event) {
    setTimeout( function(){ sizeText(); }, 360)
} })
```

Considering it takes 250ms to appear, I added a callback `sizeText()` at 360ms.
This is so that I can get the dimensions of the box and then calculate some text to fit in. If you're wondering why did I add the 360ms "afterOpen", it's because the callback doesn't wait till `afterOpen` for some reason.

```
function sizeText() {
   $("#img_preview_text_container").css("width", "300px");
}
```

**`sizeText`** method attempts to set the width of the div to 300px. But, nothing positive happens.

This is the html AFTER it appears on screen:

```
<div class="featherlight-content"><button class="featherlight-close-icon featherlight-close" aria-label="Close">✕</button><div id="previewCompleteContainer" class="featherlight-inner">
        <img src="https://example.com/Guzman.jpg?629" alt="" style="width:100%;" id="preview_image_img">
        <div id="img_preview_text_container" style="position: absolute; top:120px; left:56px"><div id="custom1Text" style="background-color: red; width: auto; height: auto; white-space: nowrap; display: inline-block;">GuzmanO</div></div>
        </div></div>
```

I would expect

```
$("#img_preview_text_container").css("width", "300px");
```

to update the div but it's not happening.  No error it just doesn't work.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: make sure that you are calling `sizeText()` after the lightbox opened.

Comment: Yes, it's being called after, that's why the settimeout is there.

Comment: Check in inspector width of div. It seems that you code is working properly.

Comment: Yes bro, I checked inspector that's why I'm on here asking this.

Comment: It would be better if you could showcase the code using stackoverflow's snippet editor or push the same on a dummy url to see what's exactly happening around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above is that I need to bind my jQuery css change.
The css change was appearing the second time the Lightbox was appearing but not the first.  To fix this instead of calling the `featherlight` as before.  I switched it to bind like so:

```
$("#plate_preview_btn").featherlight("#previewCompleteContainer", 
                                       { afterOpen: sizeText() } );
```